# Is there an equivalent for Chrome's 'setBadgeText' in Firefox Add-on SDK?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Chrome's method `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText` overlays text on top of the extensions icon. This is handy if you want to display total unread mails for example.

Is there an equivalent method when developing a [Firefox Addon SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.11/) extension, or what is the best way to change the icon at runtime?

As of version 1.11 of SDK I can't find similar method in Firefox Add-on SDK API.

Comment: As of Firefox 48, you can use WebExtensions to create add-ons. You can use the `browserAction` API and do the same a Chrome using this code: `browserAction.setBadgeText()`. Check out the page on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/BrowserAction/setBadgeText)

Answer (score 7):

**Note**: This answer does not work any more in Firefox 38+ due to the removal of the widget module. Use [one of the buttons from the ui module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui) instead.

---

I've ported the `chrome.browserAction` API to Firefox, and published it as a Jetpack module, see **https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib**

If you're familiar with the `chrome.browserAction` API, using this module can't be easier. Even if you have never created a Firefox add-on before, you can get started within a few minutes:

1. Install the add-on SDK ([instructions from Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/installation.html)).
2. Activate the SDK (by running `addon-sdk`) and create the boilerplate files (`cfx init`).
3. Download my browser-action Jetpack library ([instructions](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib#installation)).
4. Edit your add-on's `package.json`, and add `"browser-action"` as a dependency.

At this point, you've set up all prerequisites. What remains is the creation of the browser action.

### Example

This add-on adds a browser action near the location bar, which shows a popup on click. When you type something in the input field within this popup, the tab's title is changes to the field's value.

#### `lib/main.js`

```js
// lib/main.js
var badge = require('browserAction').BrowserAction({
    default_icon: 'images/icon19.png', // optional
    default_title: 'Badge title',      // optional; shown in tooltip
    default_popup: 'popup.html'        // optional
});

badge.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    require('sdk/tabs').activeTab.title = message;
});
```

#### `data/popup.html`

```html
<!-- (Example) Please avoid inline JavaScript/CSS in your production code -->
<body style="width:200px;">
  Demo: This is a popup page.<br>
  Uses <code>extension.sendMessage</code> to notify the background page,
  which in turn changes the current tab's title to below value <br>
  <input onkeyup="extension.sendMessage(this.value);" style="display:block;">
</body>
```

Here's a short screencast of the result (note: tooltip color is slightly off; [recorded with byzanz](https://askubuntu.com/a/201018/45058)):

[image: screencast]

Answer (score 6):

In `firefox 36` you can add badges (text) to your addon's buttons ..

```
var { ToggleButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/toggle");

var button = ToggleButton({
    id: "my-button1",
    label: "my button1",
    icon: "./icon-16.png",
    onChange: changed,
    badge: 0,
    badgeColor: "#00AAAA"
  });

function changed(state) {
  button.badge = state.badge + 1;
  if (state.checked) {
    button.badgeColor = "#AA00AA";
  }
  else {
    button.badgeColor = "#00AAAA";
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#Badged_buttons

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Is there a way to position the badge at the bottom?

Comment: In order to provide a consistent UI and UX, the badge position cannot be changed – I also don't think that you can change that in Google Chrome, but correct me if I'm wrong. However, if you use low level API, you *could* actually register a stylesheet for the browser, and change that position; but it's not something I recommend for two reasons: first, as said, the UI should be consistent. Second, you're using CSS that depends on badge implementation, and if that changes, you'll have your position broken – for the record, it's already change between Fx Release and Nightly.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no direct equivalent in the Add-on SDK. However, the [`widget` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.11/packages/addon-kit/widget.html) that you are probably using can display any HTML content and not just an icon. And you can script that HTML content, e.g. to show some text when necessary. I tried it with the following `lib/main.js`:

```js
var {data} = require("self");

var icon = require("widget").Widget({
  id: "my-widget",
  label: "My Widget",
  contentURL: data.url("icon.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("icon.js"),
  onClick: function()
  {
    icon.port.emit("setBadgeText", "123");
  }
});
```

It uses `icon.html` file to display the icon and sends a `setBadgeText` message to the attached content script whenever the text on top of the icon needs to change. Here is the `data/icon.html` file I tested with:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      #badgeText
      {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        font: 8px Sans-Serif;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #C00000;
        border: 1px solid #800000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico">
    <div id="badgeText" hidden="true"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I didn't invest too much effort to make the text look like Chrome's badge text, you can probably improve the styling. The text is hidden by default (I used the [HTML5 `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-hidden) for simplicity). And the `data/icon.js` content script isn't too complicated either:

```js
self.port.on("setBadgeText", function(text)
{
  var element = document.getElementById("badgeText");
  element.textContent = text;
  element.hidden = (text == null);
});
```

It receives the `setBadgeText` message and sets the text in the HTML document accordingly. It will also hide the `badgeText` element if it receives `null` as badge text.

Comment: Does this approach is applicable to a Toolbar button (which is to the right of the address bar)?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: No. The `toolbarbutton` library (not part of the Add-on SDK but you probably mean this one) create only basic XUL buttons, not very fancy.

Comment: Yes, the add-on we creating is a kind of mixup (I guess) of Add-on SDK and XUL. Nonetheless thank you, for the answer. Also, thank you for your wonderful Adblock Plus plug-in which I use it since I've started using Firefox in 2008 :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not documented in MDN, but action and toggle button also accepts [icon property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#ActionButton%28options%29) as base64 encoded image. By knowing this fact it is easy to create, for example, page-worker, and to use html canvas element to draw tooltip over an image icon, and to return that with `canvas.toDataURL()` method.