# Html popup iframe in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have added a menu item to the `contentAreaContextMenu` (right-click) menu and I need the menu item when clicked to open an HTML page as a popup, much like the way you see [this "Google news" one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075697/replicating-google-chrome-browser-actions-popup-effect-in-a-firefox-extension). I have read that an `<iframe>` is used for this but after so much reading I still don't kow how to get the popup to open and show the HTML page (`popup.html`).

If anyone has a suggestion or knows how to do this please help. Its my first Firefox extension.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to capture the click event and then just call the functon openDialog( URL );